# Save soft proof preview to file

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, printing, soft-proofing

Is there any way to save the **soft proof preview** (Ctrl+Y in *Photoshop CS 5*) to a file?

Important: **The simulation of paper color must be included!**

If not in Photoshop, is there any other software able to do that? (Lightroom or OpenSource)

---

Background: 
I ordered a canvas print and it looks quite different than the original print, as I forgot the soft proof before. The print is alright, I want to use it. But I also need a big print on paper (a screen shot won't do it), which looks equal to the one on canvas. Notice: One can hardly see a difference between the picture on screen and on paper. So how can I get a Jpeg file which on screen looks equal to the print on canvas?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't *really* an answer to your question as asked, but it isn't really just a comment either. The "simulate paper color" option probably isn't going to do nearly what you want. It's a bit heavy-handed, to say the least, and while it can be occasionally useful for perceptual purposes when preparing an image, if you could manage to save it and print it to another medium, you'll find that your "whites" in the final image are a lot darker and more colourful than they are in the target image. The blacks/darks for matte media soft proofs also tend to get dragged up a lot higher than they should be when that option is active. Again, that's useful for perceptual purposes while working, but not terribly accurate.

Something I would try is taking a screen shot of white with the proofing option on, just so that you can sample the resulting colour. (If you try sampling directly from the image, you get the underlying real image colour, not the soft proof colour.) Somewhere between that colour and white there will be a colour that more-or-less accurately represents the medium the image was being proofed for; the average of that colour and 255,255,255 will probably be pretty close. Create a solid layer of that colour below your image, then set your image to one of the darken modes (multiply will probably be best). You may have to fiddle with the black point just a touch to get a good match.

Yes, it's all eyeballing, though you *can* use a screenshot of a soft proof and colour sampling through the info panel to assist you in the process. You should be able to get something that's indistinguishable to civilians, other than the fact that one picture has a canvas texture and the other does not. The only way I can think of to get numbers-accurate is to use a reflected-light colorimeter and test prints.

Comment: Okay thanks for proposing this workaround! So there is *really* no functionality to apply the changes done for a soft proof preview to the actual file? The accuracy is not *that important*. I was rather looking for a fast way of doing this. I'll wait one more day, then I'll accept your answer! thanks!

Comment: @thewaywewalk - No, there's no way to apply the effect. The idea of the soft proof is to be "soft"; to let you see what will happen to the image file when it's output with its current values. Applying those changes would essentially double the effect when printed (and that would, of course, be Adobe's fault - it's never the user, right?), so it would be a dangerous thing to have as an option.